# How can I determine, programmatically, if a volume is available (online) on z/OS?

Tags: dataset, zos

If I look in a dataset catalog and determine there is a dataset with a particular name on a particular volume, how can I then determine if that volume is 'online'?

For example, if I use the CSI (catalog search interface) to look for 'MY.DATASET', I can get the volume  but how can I determine if the volume is online?
I know I can issue various operator commands but I would like something programmatic (from C ideally, but assembler works) where I don't have to 'scrape' the output.
For example, I could issue:

```
d u,dasd,online,,65536'
```

to see the online datasets but the output isn't intended to be programmed to I don't think.

Comment: Maybe change "dataset is online" to "volume is online" in the second paragraph.  Also it might be good to indicate what language or environment you're coding this in.

Comment: Good points @TomBrennan. I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the `ucbscan` macro - see this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=wto-ucbscan-scan-ucbs

Comment: Thanks - yes - this definitely looks like what I am after. Here's the specific location I ended up: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=usu-description

Answer (score 1):

Check out the LSPACE macro.  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=contents-accessing-vtoc-dadsm-macros

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know of that macro. The primary downside to that service is I have to wait at least 1 second to find out the volume is offline, so it would be fine for one dataset on one volume, but not 10K datasets of 10K volumes 

Answer (score 0):

If `LSPACE` is too slow, and it probably is due to the need to read every VTOC, then the `USBSCAN` macro is probably the best.  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=wto-ucbscan-scan-ucbs and use `DEVCLASS=DASD`

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

You can use VOLUMEENTRIES keyword on LISTCAT command to check if the VOLUME is online or not.

For example

```
LISTCAT ENT('your.dsn.in.question') VOLUMEENTRIES('ABCDEF')
```

Will result

```
      LISTING FROM CATALOG -- SYS1.VOLCAT.VGENERAL      
IDC3012I ENTRY **ABCDEF** NOT FOUND                                                
IDC3007I VSAM CATALOG RETURN-CODE IS 8                                         
IDC1566I ** ABCDEF NOT LISTED                                                  
IDC0014I LASTCC=4                                                              
***
```

Comment: Thanks @kolusu - but I don't think the output is a 'programmable interface', i.e. the LISTCAT developers could change that output on a whim and bust a tool going against the output. If it _is_ a programmable interface (someone that works on LISTCAT TSO program?) then that would work.